# What is cost function in neural network?

Tags: neural-network

Could someone please explain to me why it is so important the cost function in a neural network, what is its purpose?

Note: I'm just introducing me to the subject of neural networks, but failed to understand it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In artificial neural networks, the cost function to return a number
>   representing how well the neural network performed to map training
>   examples to correct output.

[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_function) and [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-01-principles-of-microeconomics-fall-2007/lecture-notes/14_01_lec13.pdf)

In other words, after you train a neural network, you have a math model that was trained to adjust its weights to get a better result. The weights and the activation function of each neuron results in a main function, which is the neural network. It is a cost function and its propose is to be adjusted (training step) to produce better results.

Answer (score 1):

Cost function returns a scalar value called 'cost' , that tells how good or bad your model is. There are several cost functions that can be used. Less cost represent a good model. The reason cost functions are used in neural networks is that 'cost is used by models to improve'